# CASE WHEN for dates in different formats

Tags: db2

I have a table (my_t) with columns : `col1, col2, col3.`

- col2 is in the format : `2000-01-01:00:00:00` and is in `DATE` Format
- col3 is in the format: `2000-01-01` and is `CHARACTER(10)` format (note that col3 has many NULLS)

I am trying to write the following code (if var3>var2 then update var1 else leave var1 as is):

```
select *,
case when var3 is not null and cast(var3 as date)> cast(var2 as date) then 'abc' else var1 end as var1
from my_t;
```

But I keep getting this error : `bad date external representation ....`

I tried:

```
select *,
case 
    when col3 is not null and to_date(col3, 'yyyy-mm-dd') > col2 then 'abc' 
    else col1 
end as var1
from my_t;
```

But I get an error: `Bad value 0 for day`

Is there something I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible example  of your problem in a form like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/c0aN9OSU)? Post the corresponding link with such an example.

Comment: In general, you need to figure out what rows that contain malformed data and fix them. I typically use functions with a continue handler that maps invalid data to an extreme value that can never exist (or null). But I agree with Mark, you need to provide some sample data that demonstrates the problem if you expect suggestions